# How to write normal List.Add method with encapsulation?

Tags: c#, list, listview, encapsulation

I am new to C# and I added a List to my code. It works perfectly, but I want to do this with encapsulation as well. I did the beginning but I stuck at one point. Thank you for your answers.
This is the classes of my normal List.

```
namespace Data
{
    public static class ListItem2Operations
    {
        public static List<ListItem2> GetMenuItems(string type)
        {
            List<ListItem2> items = new List<ListItem2>();

            items.Add(new ListItem2("image/hotel_porto_bay_rio_internacional_de_luxe_800x600.jpg", "0px,0px,0px", "lux"));
            items.Add(new ListItem2("image/hotel_porto_bay_rio_internacional_rooftop_pool_800x600.jpg", "0px,0px,0px", "lux"));
            items.Add(new ListItem2("image/hotel_porto_bay_serra_golf_library_800x600.jpg", "0px,0px,0px", "nice"));
            items.Add(new ListItem2("image/hotel_porto_bay_serra_golf_living_room_800x600.jpg", "0px,25px,0px", "lux"));
            items.Add(new ListItem2("image/hotel_porto_bay_serra_golf_suite_800x600.jpg", "0px,25px,0px", "nice"));
            items.Add(new ListItem2("image/lhotel_porto_bay_sao_paulo_suite_lhotel_living_room_800x600.jpg", "0px,25px,0px", "nice"));
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is where I initialize my variables.

```
namespace Data
{
    public class ListItem2
    {
        public string Src { get; set; }

        public string Pos { get; set; }

        public string Category { get; set; }
        public ListItem2(string Src, string Pos, string Category)
        {

            this.Src = Src;
            this.Pos = Pos;
            this.Category = Category;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my initializations for encapsulation;

```
class Operations
{
    private string src;
    public string _src
    {
        get { return src; }
        set { src = value; }
    }
    private string pos;
    public string _pos
    {
        get { return pos; }
        set { pos = value; }
    }
    private string category;
    public string _category
    {
        get { return category; }
        set { category = value; }
    }

    public Operations(string Src, string Pos, string Category)
    {

        this._src = src;
        this._pos = pos;
        this._category = category;
    }

    List<string> items = new List<string>();
}
```

Thank you for your answers and have a good day.

Comment: so what exactly is your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to add items to my list but the classic List.Add methos is not working I don't know why. The Visual Studio does not see List.

Comment: Do you have a namespace  `using System.Collections.Generic` on top of your `ListItem2Operations`?

Comment: To which list? Where? I'm sorry but I have no idea of what your problem is.

Comment: Yes I have @DolceVita

Comment: @Kilazur to the "items" list. I am sorry if I did something wrong in the decleration as well.

Comment: @daisy8520 ok, you have to edit your question and tell us more clear where exactly you get a problem  (the line in the code provided) and what visual studio tells you. Can you do this please? Your question is totally unclear right now

Comment: which `item` list you are not able to access? From where you are not able to access it?